# get undefined when I try to retrieve data from firebase - ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Given the Firebase database structure in the picture is it right to retrieve data in this way? (I want to retrieve awayteam, awayteamgoals, hometeam, hometeamgoals and phase of each node)

```
firebase.database().ref('matches/');
```

[image]

I have this provider:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';


@Injectable()
export class MatchData {

  constructor(private http: Http) {

  }

  getMatchList(): any {
    return firebase.database().ref('matches/');
  }
}
```

The constructor of the page that uses the provider looks like this:

```
 constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, private navParams: NavParams, private matchData: MatchData) {
    this.navCtrl = navCtrl;
    this.matchData = matchData; // matchData is the name of the provider

    this.matchData.getMatchList().on('value', snapshot => {
      let rawList = [];
      snapshot.forEach( snap => {
        rawList.push({
          awayteam: snap.val().awayteam,
          hometeam: snap.val().hometeam,
        });
      });
      this.matchList = rawList;
      console.log(this.matchList); // undefined is returned here
    });
  }
}
```

When I `console.log` `matchlist` I get `undefined`.

Comment: Where are you `console.log()`ing to check for `matchlist`?

Comment: @ABabin  I've edited the question code.

Comment: I'm having trouble duplicating your issue. I've mimicked your `snapshot.forEach(...)` code and everything works as it should for me. Try `console.log(snapshot.val())` before the `snapshot.forEach(...)` and see if you're actually getting the `matches` data.

Comment: if I console.log("some text") before snapshot.forEach it doesn't print out anything in my browser console. What could be the cause of this strange behaviour?

Comment: Are you sure that the component that's using the `MatchData` is actually being constructed? The undefined console entry that you thought was from `console.log(this.matchlist)` might be from somewhere else and the constructor isn't being run at all. That's the only reason I can think of that happening. Even if the `snapshot.forEach` isn't doing what it's supposed to, when you assign `rawList` to `this.matchList`, it should, at the very least, give you an empty array (`[]`) when you log it.

Comment: @ABabin Does Firebase allow not logged in user to access the database? maybe it's because of this that I get undefined.. by the way, I'm sure that the constructor of the page is called.

Comment: It depends on the rules you've set for your Firebase database, but if you did try to access data unauthorized, there'd be errors in the console. I don't think it has to do with Firebase. If you assign `rawList` to `this.matchList`, a `console.log(this.matchList)` immediately after should not, under any circumstance, give undefined. Can you try putting a `console.log("foo")` before the call to the `getMatchList()` function? Also, screenshot the console and add it to your post, if you don't mind.